# jquery doesn't seem to recognize left-margin, what can I do?

Tags: jquery, css, margin

I don't use jquery very often, but I wanted to animate a side bar. I have a 670px sidebar menu with a -670 left-margin. On mouseover, I would like the left-margin to change to 0px...exposing the hidden content. On mouseout it should return to -670. It seems like the code I wrote may have worked if I were just dealing with the margin(all four sides), instead of left-margin(only the left). But when I specify left-margin in my code I get errors. What are my options?

right now I have "margin" instead of "left-margin", but that's just a place holder.
here's my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

//menu pull out
$(document).ready(function() {
 $('#left_menu').mouseover(function() {
  $('#left_menu').animate({
     margin: 0
  }, 1000, function() {
  });
});

//menu close
$('#left_menu').mouseout(function() {
  $('#left_menu').animate({
    margin:-670
  }, 1000, function() {

  });
});
});
</script>
```

Comment: Just to check, you are using "margin-left", and not "left-margin", yes? If you post the code you're actually having problems with, that might help us more.

Comment: Are you sure that `mouseover` is firing? Have you tried e.g. `alert('test')` or sth like that to check event?

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 $('#left_menu').mouseover(function() {
  $('#left_menu').animate({
     marginLeft: '0px'
  }, 1000, function() {
  });
});

//menu close
$('#left_menu').mouseout(function() {
  $('#left_menu').animate({
    marginLeft: '-670px'
  }, 1000, function() {

  });
});
});
```

Comment: @TheBetterWork Check my edit please. Miss used margin with marginLeft. If it still doesn't work please make a jsFiddle I sort it out for you.

Comment: @ThisBetterWork Have you tried considering this as an answer? Did you found a solution?

Answer (score 1):

Are you writing left margin as `margin-left`, if that is the case it wont work, you should use `leftMargin` instead.

Comment: ooooh. Yes, I was using margin-left, however....now I changed it to leftMargin and although dreamweaver doesn't detect any errors, the code isn't working. nothing happens :(

thanks for catching that though!

Comment: dreamweaver wont show any errors, looks for errors in firebug

Comment: Also please specify the unit for margin -eg 670px instead of 670